# Wordpress shortcode function - pagination on taxonomy template

Tags: php, wordpress, shortcode, taxonomy, custom-taxonomy

I have the code below which is working properly when i use it on wp pages. On taxonomy template (taxonomy.php) pagination on start working properly, but after few pages while the query still has posts to display breaks with 404 error.

For example it has 29 posts to display with 4 posts per page. Up to page 6 everything works ok, when i click on next (page 7) it displays the index.php template with 404 error while the query results should create 8 pages.

```
<?php 
function get_featured_projects_shortcode_function(){
  $return =  '';

  global $paged;
      if ( get_query_var('paged') ) {
      $paged = get_query_var('paged');
      } elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) {
      $paged = get_query_var('page');
      } else {
      $paged = 1;
      }

  $posts_per_page = 4;

  $category_name = single_cat_title("", false);

  $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'project',
            'tax_query' => array(
                    array( 
                    'taxonomy' => 'project_category',
                    'field'    => 'name',
                    'terms'    => array( $category_name ) ),
            ),
             'posts_per_page' => $posts_per_page,
             'post_status' => 'publish',
             'orderby' => 'date',
             'order' => 'DESC',
             'paged' => $paged,
             'page' => $paged
          );

  $query = new WP_Query($args); 

  $total_found_posts = $query->found_posts;
  $total_page = ceil($total_found_posts / $posts_per_page);

  if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    $return .= '<div class="proj-holder">';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
            $query->the_post();
            $return .=  get_the_title();
    }
      $return .= '</div>';
  }

  if(function_exists('wp_pagenavi')) {
         $return .='<div class="page-navigation">'.wp_pagenavi(array('query' => $query, 'echo' => false)).'</div>';
     } else {
         $return.='<div class="posts-links-next-prev">
         <span class="prev-posts-links">'.get_previous_posts_link('<< Previous ').'</span>
         <span class="next-posts-links">'.get_next_posts_link(' Next >>', $total_page).'</span>
         </div>';
     }

  return $return;

 wp_reset_postdata();
}
?>
```

Comment: what is `posts per page` set to in the wp-admin?

Comment: it was set to 5 by the theme! Thank you very much! i set it to 4 and it works great! Add it as an answer if you want

Comment: Sweet - happy to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had similar problems before -

My problem was, that the `posts per page` was set to something else in the wp-admin and resultet in wordpress doing weird calculations for how many pages there should be.

If you match those two up, it should work fine.

And by the comments section, we can see that, luckily, it also solved this problem.